# Failing to retrieve my Notepad data. Any trick/workaround?

Tags: notepad, undo, info

I'm an active user of Notepad, even though it disappointed me a lot of times because of it lacks of recovery features.

My current problem is: I jotted down some things (which I don't really remember anything of what I wrote) in an **opened** Notepad file, I didn't save the file in the first place. 
I came to delete the first line of what I wrote, and I suddenly highlighted everything and got it deleted quickly, without intention.

The thing is, **the file is not saved**, otherwise, I would've tried to close it directly (without saving the changes to it). + I tried to use the **"undo" feature** that Notepad provides; very bad that it is limited to (one step backward); because after I lost what I wrote, I mistakenly typed on some things trying to recover what I wrote, and the "undo" retrieved what I mistakenly typed, which is the 1 word itself.

I kept the file opened, and I saved it empty now, in hope that anyone has a method/trick/workaround to have my things back.

Comment: Notepad saves text only and what you see is what you get, no file history is saved and it's rare for any program to keep that kind of history in their output files. If you saved an empty text file then all you have is an empty text file. If you need more than the basic functionality of Notepad then you need a better program.

Answer (score 4):

As you already mentioned the standard Windows Notepad doesn't implement a real undo history but rather just a one step mechanism. As such there is no record of what changes you made. In addition, as it's just writing normal text files, there is also nothing to be gained by saving the file.

The data you accidentally overwrote before you saved the file is lost. You might want to consider to switch to something like Notepad++ or Notepad2 which at least should have a history or other similar programs.

Comment: +1 for Notepad++, I've been an almost daily user for years.

Comment: It depends on how you use it. To actually quickly jot notes I actually kind of find it too heavy but haven't jet found a good alternative. So Notepad and Notepad++ it is for me (for the most part).